# Can an angular component be identified within an HTML element?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, components

I want to create a table filter component that falls in line with the structure and syntax of the `matSort/mat-sort-header` components in Angular Material. The way that it is created there is to put a `matSort` directive at the `<table>` element, and then for each column you want to be sortable, you put the `mat-sort-header` directive. The interesting thing, however, is that a column which is not given the `mat-sort-header` directive's  element is nothing more than text in the `<th>`, and a column with the `mat-sort-header` directive gets that column (with the included text) turned into a button.

I looked into the source code of the `@angular/material/sort` (https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/sort/sort-header.html), and found that the mat-sort-header is actually decorated as a `@Component`, not a `@Directive`, complete with its own template. However, this goes somewhat against my understanding of components. I know that a Component ***is*** a directive, but I didn't know that you could put a directive within a native HTML element and get the innards to generate HTML.

So here is how you create a sortable table header:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
 ...
```

I read the mat-sort-header as an attribute directive, but source code shows that it's a *component directive*. Is this in the documentation anywhere? Is this doable?

Along the same lines, if I want to make my own filter/sort component that parallels this structure, is this something that Angular supports?

Comment: You'll find it also on [MatDatepicker's code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/month-view.html), where [`mat-calendar-body` selector](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/77b0e0ea8a6b598bdabd10ca33cb1c2aa5d5c331/src/material/datepicker/calendar-body.ts#L45) brings in all the table body (`tr`'s and `td`'s).

Comment: Thanks! Did I just miss this in their documentation? This answers SO many of my questions about creating components that you can incorporate in angular material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All directives are components under the hood. It's all about the decorators. The directive decorator lets the compiler know that you're not about to use a template and you're going to *typically* use the component to either change the DOM layout or change the appearance or behavior of an element. (See: [link](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)).

`mat-sort-header` is still a component, it has a template, it's just being selected by using an attribute. That's seen in the `selector: [mat-sort-header]`. They could have also made it a directive, but because they are needing the view/styling, it needed to be a component.

Comment: I thought it was the other way around, that all components are directives (documentation says the three types are structural, attribute, and component).

Comment: I have to clarify my question, and apologize for not being clear. The thing is that components, according to documentation, I thought were THE element, so seeing something like <th mat-table-header ...> throws off my understanding of what is possible with angular. If mat-table-header is a template, how does angular determine where to put in the template? It seems like THIS usage expands the ability much further, so I'm not sure why this is not clearer in the documentation.

Comment: In terms of Angular, yes, you're right. Angular labels their components as directives. But in all other frameworks/web standards, they are known as components.

Comment: Well you answered your own question in your first reply!

Components are just Directives with a template. Your Directive metadata determines if it has a template or not. `@Component` has a property for "template" or "templateUrl", `@Directive` doesn't. A component can be selected via an element or an attribute. The usual selector is as an element, and is the preferred way according to the Angular styleguide. Directives are as attributes. But you have a component be selectable by element or attribute!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers and the help, this is the disconnect I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

My confusion here was in assumption, go figure.

In my original post, I showed the code as

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

but I have also seen it written as

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

(notice the missing `th` element).

It's that second one I saw that sparked my question, and after mulling it around in my head, I came to the (incorrect) conclusion that `mat-header-cell` is a **component**. That didn't make sense, how could two components exist within the same element? After all, Angular themselves said it [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#description):

> Angular components are a subset of directives, always associated with
>   a template. Unlike other directives, only one component can be
>   instantiated per an element in a template.

So I go digging around to accomplish one of two goals: understand Angular better, or prove that Angular is lying. Looking at the table source code, [documentation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/cell.ts#L70) shows that `mat-header-cell` is actually a directive, and it's recognized with two possible selectors.

```
/** Header cell template container that adds the right classes and role. */
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-header-cell, th[mat-header-cell]',
  host: {
    'class': 'mat-header-cell',
    'role': 'columnheader',
  },
})
export class MatHeaderCell extends CdkHeaderCell {
  constructor(columnDef: CdkColumnDef,
              elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
    super(columnDef, elementRef);
    elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add(`mat-column-${columnDef.cssClassFriendlyName}`);
  }
}
```

Doh...

This means that the line up top STILL only contains one component. So everything is still intact, Angular is freakin' honest, and I learned something. Hooray for open source!

Everyone keep your points and credit for the answer, I just wanted to clarify why I asked, and the final click that happened in my brain where it made sense.